# Swipe only image from fragment not complete fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have created an fragment with some view component. I need to swipe only image from that component but with my code complete fragment is getting swapped. How can I swaped only image of the Fragment
Bellow is my code. I have used ViewPager to do swipe fragment

```
public class DetailedSwiperImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
private Context mContext;
FoodDetail foodDetails;
private List<FoodDetail> foodDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();
private final int currentPosition;

public DetailedSwiperImageAdapter(Context fragmentContext, List<FoodDetail> foodDetail, int position) {
    mContext = fragmentContext;
    foodDetailsList = foodDetail;
    currentPosition = position;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return foodDetailsList.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detailed_fragment, container,
            false);
    foodDetails = foodDetailsList.get(position);
    View view = populateDataForDetailedLayout(viewLayout, foodDetails);
    container.addView(view);
    return view;
}

/*
    * fetch the data from the timeline and display it in the detailed screen
    */
private View populateDataForDetailedLayout(View viewLayout, FoodDetail foodDetails) {
    ((TextView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.detailed_meal_type)).setText(foodDetails.getFoodType().name());

    ImageView dishImageView = (ImageView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.dish_image_view);
    File imgFile = new File(foodDetails.getFoodImageLocalPath());
    if (imgFile.exists()) {
        dishImageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(imgFile));
    }
    final TextView detaileMessage = (TextView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.detaile_message);
    TextView detaileLocation = (TextView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.detaile_location);
    TextView detaileDishName = (TextView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.detaile_dish_name);
    TextView detaileTime = (TextView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.detaile_time);
    ImageView emojiImage = (ImageView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.emoji_detailed);
    detaileDishName.setText(foodDetails.getFoodName());
    String smrtMsg = foodDetails.getSmartmessage();
    if (smrtMsg != null) {
        smrtMsg = smrtMsg.replaceAll("[\n\r]", "");
        detaileMessage.setText(smrtMsg);
    }
    if (foodDetails.getIntentEmojiUnicode() != null) {
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(RemoteUtils.getIntentImageURIString(foodDetails.getIntentEmojiUnicode(), null, "khanapal")).into(emojiImage);

    }

    CharSequence time = DateUtils.getRelativeDateTimeString(mContext,
            foodDetails.getStartTime().getTime(), DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS, DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS, 0);
    detaileTime.setText(time);
    String location = "";

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(foodDetails.getStreet())) {
        location = foodDetails.getStreet();
    } else if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(foodDetails.getLocationName())) {
        location = foodDetails.getLocationName();
    } else if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(foodDetails.getCity())) {
        location = foodDetails.getCity();
    } else if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(foodDetails.getCountry())) {
        location = foodDetails.getCountry();
    }
    location += " - " + foodDetails.getLocationUnformattedAddress() + "";
    if (foodDetails.getLocationUnformattedAddress() == null) location = "No location";
    detaileLocation.setText(location);

    //used for message edting on click of smart message text editor
    detaileMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String message = detaileMessage.getText().toString();
            editMessage(message, detaileMessage);
        }
    });
    return viewLayout;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a ViewDragHelper for your image.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/ViewDragHelper.html